# jwt signature verifying not working nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt

First of all, I'm boarding an existing backend project that is made in nodejs. Like I get used to, I like to verify the correct functioning of everything made so far, however, something is not working properly when the auth middleware tries to verify a jwt.

Let's use two example endpoints in this case: `POST /log-in` and `PUT /update/:id`

I traced the code and found out this is where the `/log-in` signs and creates the token:

```
const token = jwt.sign({ id: foundUser, rut: foundUser.rut }, process.env.SECRET_KEY as Secret, { expiresIn: '7 days' })
```

I think there's nothing wrong with the above sign because, as expected, it returns the jwt to the response.

However, when I try to test an auth-based endpoint like, e.g. `/update/:id`, the middleware fails trying to do:

```
const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY as Secret)
```

This project is supposedly working fine in production, so I don't know what may be happening here. I tested the payload in https://jwt.io/ and it says '**Signature Verified**'. Here is the validation:

[image]

Let's clarify I don't mind sharing the secret key and payload because I'm in a development environment, just testing with dummy data and I can change the secret key anytime. So, any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Did you check what are you passing in the token when verifying? Is it token or some object? Check if the sceret is passing correctly? Are you using jsonwebtoken?

Comment: Hello, I'm passing the token, not the object. I debugged both elements (token and secret key) before the sign token line, they are both arriving correctly just before that. Yes, I'm using jsonwebtoken version "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",

Comment: strange, it shouldn't be that difficult to verify JWT. Can you share more code from the module you are creating token.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue while using express and react. What really worked for me was removing the 'Bearer' prefix when sending request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).